# Cannot transform a Json into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a `json` file like that:

```
{
    "info": [
        {
            "product": "ABC",
            "email-adr": "abc08@gmail.com",
            "Gender": "M",
            "Name": "João",
            "id": "1069",
            "mobile": "iOS | 9.1",
            "client": " "
        },
```

I tried to:

```
data2 = pd.read_json('file.json', encoding=str)
```

but got a `df` with a single column:

```
                      info
0  {u'id':u'1069',u'client'..
```

What is the best way to read this `json` file to a pandas `df`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass as argument only the inner object:

```
import json

z="""{
"info":
[
{"product": "ABC", "email-adr": "abc08@gmail.com", "Gender": "M", "Name": "João", "id": "1069", "mobile": "iOS | 9.1", "client": " " }]}"""
>>> pd.DataFrame(json.loads(z)['info'])

  Gender  Name client        email-adr    id     mobile product
0      M  João         abc08@gmail.com  1069  iOS | 9.1     ABC
```

---

To load a json file:

```
with open("file.json", "r") as f:
  data = json.load(f)
```

Then you can do

```
pd.DataFrame(data['info'])
```

Comment: as I have several lines in this file, I tried: df=pd.DataFrame(json.loads('file.json')['info']) and received the following error: ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

Comment: This is not how you load a json file. Let me edit and show you